# Location manager accuracy not very accurate

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I am having an issue with sending location to other users. I using Parse.com as my backend and I use this code to get a location:

```
-(void)sendLocation{



    if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]){

        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

    }
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];



}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; //kill it NOW or we have duplicates

    if(!self.haveLocation) {

        self.haveLocation=YES;

        NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);

        self.currentLocation = newLocation;
        self.currentLocationGeoPoint= [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLocation:self.currentLocation];

}
```

If I send myself a message from my current location and then open the message to view it, by comparing the current location circle with the pin dropped I can see they aren't in the same place and a fair distance apart.

I have the BOOL var haveLocation to make sure it is only refreshed once. Do I need to refresh it more times or something? Any pointers on how to make this more accurate would be really appreciated! Thanks

I tried following the apple example LocateMe:

I now have:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

    NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];

    if (locationAge > 5.0) return;

    // test that the horizontal accuracy does not indicate an invalid measurement
    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) return;

    // test the measurement to see if it is more accurate than the previous measurement
    if (self.bestEffortAtLocation == nil || self.bestEffortAtLocation.horizontalAccuracy > newLocation.horizontalAccuracy) {
        // store the location as the "best effort"
        self.bestEffortAtLocation = newLocation;


        if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= locationManager.desiredAccuracy) {

            [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

            //this code after getting the location
            NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
}

}
```

}

However when I tap send location it just runs forever and doesn't stop updating.. I have `locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;` set too.

Comment: Have you tried not killing the update and just logging the results to see if they vary?
Geoloc can be tricky, and like Rob said there is a chance that it's gaining accuracy after a few tries.

Comment: You could also set the accuracy precision to "best"

Comment: I used this locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location manager may send you several updates as it improves its accuracy. This is a feature designed to give you information it as as quickly as possible, while eventually getting the best information to you (at least up to the accuracy you requested). You are actively avoiding those updates, so you are likely getting the least accurate information.

You should check the `horizontalAccuracy` to determine if it is accurate enough for your use.

Note that you cannot compare `horizontalAccuracy` to `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`. "Best" is a constant -1. You need to compare it to what you need (in meters), and probably set a timeout to give up if it takes too long to get there (the system may not be able to provide you an arbitrarily accurate value.)

Comment: I just looked into horizontalAccuracy and found an example by Apple called LocateMe. I have edited my question above. The problem is now that the location never stops updating.

Comment: Correct. `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` is -1. You're not going to get accuracy that good or better.

Comment: just saw your edit so I can do if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= 10) [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; and that will give a 10m radius?

Comment: Correct. Accuracy is in meters, with a couple of "special" accuracies for "Best" (-1) and "Best for navigation" (-2).

Comment: Was wondering what accuracy might be suitable for sending a user your location in a messaging app. 10m is super slow to update but surely if it's more than that it's not very accurate.

Comment: Messaging apps often just report the city, which can get with a much lower accuracy (the fastest, 3 km, can even be sufficient). It really comes down to the user experience you want. Remember, in a messaging app, the user may be traveling quite fast (in a car for instance), so accuracy is not your only issue. You probably want to keep gathering information until the message is actually sent (forcing you to decide whether you mean "when I started" or "when I sent it." What if I start a message, fly across the country, and then hit "send?")