# Core Location Accuracy Indoor

Tags: ios, gps, core-location

How accurate are coordinates returned by `CLLocationManager` indoor with the `.desiredAccuracy` property set as `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`?

What is the error range? Between 5 to 10 meters? Would I at least be able to find out which room I am in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original Answer - 
[Location manager accuracy not very accurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078235/location-manager-accuracy-not-very-accurate)

The location manager may send you several updates as it improves its accuracy. This is a feature designed to give you information it as as quickly as possible, while eventually getting the best information to you (at least up to the accuracy you requested). You are actively avoiding those updates, so you are likely getting the least accurate information.

You should check the horizontalAccuracy to determine if it is accurate enough for your use.

Note that you cannot compare horizontalAccuracy to kCLLocationAccuracyBest. "Best" is a constant -1. You need to compare it to what you need (in meters), and probably set a timeout to give up if it takes too long to get there (the system may not be able to provide you an arbitrarily accurate value.)

Documentation for desired accuracy.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423836-desiredaccuracy

When requesting high-accuracy location data, the initial event delivered by the location service may not have the accuracy you requested. The location service delivers the initial event as quickly as possible. It then continues to determine the location with the accuracy you requested and delivers additional events, as necessary, when that data is available.
For iOS and macOS, the default value of this property is kCLLocationAccuracyBest. For watchOS, the default value is kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters.
This property is used only in conjunction with the standard location services and is not used when monitoring significant location changes.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

From `CLLocationManager`'s header:

> Type used to represent a location accuracy level in meters. The lower the value in meters, the more physically precise the location is. A negative accuracy value indicates an invalid location.

Apple doesn't specify anywhere in their docs what `CLLocationAccuracyBest` actually represents, likely because we're not guaranteed that level of accuracy. At best, CoreLocation can get you down to a couple meters, but many times — and especially indoors — you won't get that kind of reliable reading.

For room-by-room indoor ranging, you're likely to get much more reliable results using [iBeacons with CoreLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html).